# Change page layout when adding table in word using RDCOMClient

Tags: r, ms-word, rdcomclient

How to change page layout when adding table in word using RDCOMClient

Does anyone know how to change the page layout in Word using RDCOMClient, just in the page where certain table is added to the document?

My problem is to detect the page where the table is in the document, and change the layout of just that page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.